# It does not work collection queries with the condition

Tags: mysql

I need to bring to the customer a discount depending on how long it took a training course.
To find out the date of passage must first know the group ID to which the client belongs.
[image]

When I know Id of group, I can find date when started training course.
[image]

And then, determined the size of discounts by finded date
Here's a script that works great in MS SQL, but in MySql it doesn't works.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetBonus`(
idStudent CHAR(36)
)
BEGIN   
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT IdGroupe FROM GroupeStudent WHERE IdStudent = idStudent) groupeCourse) = 1 THEN 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE CourseGroupeDate datetime;
    SET CourseGroupeDate = (SELECT Date FROM CourseGroupe WHERE Id = (SELECT IdGroupe FROM GroupeStudent WHERE IdStudent = idStudent));
        IF (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH)  < 3 AND  
            (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH) > 0
            THEN SELECT * FROM Discounts WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        ELSEIF (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH) < 6 AND  
            (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH) > 3
            THEN SELECT * FROM Discounts WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001';
        ELSEIF (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH) < 12 AND  
            (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH) > 6 
            THEN SELECT * FROM Discounts WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002';
        END IF;
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

[image]

Comment: (CourseGroupeDate - INTERVAL NOW() MONTH)  returns null?

Comment: Yes, and how to fix it?

Comment: I can't tell you because you have not posted your table definitions (sample date would also be nice), I suggest you google-  MYSQL month difference - there's lots out there including SO.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will understand more.

Comment: I changed the function to find the difference of dates, which returns all well but still call to the stored procedure returns the null, and I do not understand what went wrong.

Comment: here is the code `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now())`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetBonus`(
idStudent CHAR(36)
)
BEGIN   
    IF (SELECT COUNT(groupeCourse.IdGroupe) FROM (SELECT IdGroupe FROM GroupeStudent WHERE GroupeStudent.IdStudent = idStudent) groupeCourse) = 1 THEN 
    BEGIN
    SET @CourseGroupeDate := (SELECT Date FROM CourseGroupe WHERE Id = (SELECT GroupeStudent.IdGroupe FROM GroupeStudent WHERE GroupeStudent.IdStudent = idStudent));
        IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now()))  < 3 AND  
            (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now())) > 0
            THEN SELECT * FROM Discounts WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        ELSEIF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now())) < 6 AND  
            (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now())) > 3
            THEN SELECT * FROM Discounts WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001';
        ELSEIF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now())) < 12 AND  
            (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @CourseGroupeDate, now())) > 6 
            THEN SELECT * FROM Discounts WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002';
        END IF;
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

All in the details , for example , it was necessary to specify the table name about the field **GroupeStudent.IdStudent = idStudent**